# Need to parse xml file and print element with checking an empty tag

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I need to write a perl script to parse through a XML file. If SpecialData tag has value, then I need to print the Name. I could write this 
for the following file.

For the following xml file, output should be Name-abc

```
<Data>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <SpecialData>Properties</SpecialData>
</Data>

<Data>
    <Name>mnp</Name>
</Data>
```

But in a xml file as mentioned below, SpecialData tag has an empty tag Properties. I need to write a perl script that will print the name, if SpecialData tag is there. Here the difference is Properties is an inner tag, not a value as the 1st problem. Can anyone help me to write a perl script to do this?

For the following xml file, output should be Name- abc

```
<Data>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <SpecialData>
      <Properties />
    </SpecialData>
</Data>

<Data>
    <Name>mnp</Name>
</Data>
```

Comment: Both files you have shown are not valid XML as they are both missing a root element. You can't have multiple elements in one XML document at the root level. 
 // Have you tried solving this problem yourself?

Answer (score 2):

[ *What you posted isn't a valid XML file. I'm assuming what you posted are snippets from XML files. Specifically, I assumed they are found under a root element named `root`.* ]

Using a DOM-based parser like XML::LibXML, it would look like the following:

```
for my $data_node ($doc->findnodes('/root/Data')) {
   if ($data_node->findnodes('SpecialData')) {
      say $data_node->findvalue('Name');
   }
}
```

If you don't need anything from other data nodes, you could even use the following:

```
for my $data_node ($doc->findnodes('/root/Data[SpecialData]')) {
   say $data_node->findvalue('Name');
}
```

If you don't need anything else from the data nodes, you could even use the following:

```
say for $doc->findnodes('/root/Data[SpecialData]/Name/text()');
```